# job schedule automatic in hudson

Tags: jenkins, hudson

**- Hello,

i am scheduling jobs in Hudson. want to schedule by day of week not
   by day of month. Like i want to schedule job#1 on Monday and
   Wednesday and Job#2 on Tuesday and Thursday. i tried following
   syntax,

> Blockquote

job#1 :-- 30 11  * * 1,3 
job#2 :-- 30 11  * * 2,4

> Blockquote

but job#1 got triggered on Tuesday.i think problem is in day count or syntax ?

Help is greatly appreciated !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# * * * * *  command to execute
# ┬ ┬ ┬ ┬ ┬
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
# │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
# │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
# └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

Comment: 0 30 11 ? * MON,WED * -- EVERY WEEK MONDAY & WED

Answer (score 1):

The cron expression seems fine, do you have any other build triggers? E.g. source control changes. What does build log claims have triggered job#1 build on Tuesday?
BTW do those hyphens (--) present in you build trigger?